# How do I fix {item.id} always equalling the id of the last item in my array inside of a FlatList?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
        <Text style={ styles.item }>{item.task}</Text>
        <Modal animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item.id}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      </TouchableOpacity>


<FlatList
      data={toDoList}
      extraData={toDoList}
      renderItem= {renderItem} />
    )
  }
```

This is supposed to show the Id of the flatlist item that i press inside of a Modal. When I click it however, it always defaults to the Id of the last item inside of my data, which is 5. The {item.task} at the very top is working correctly, and all my flatlist items have the correct names, but whenever I click on them, the Modal shows an Id of 5, and not their Id. How can I fix this? I also have a feature where I can add items to the flatlist, and the added buttons also have the correct names, but when click, the Modal shows the Id of the last item inside of my data(5,6,7, and so on as i add items).

Answer (score 0):

You should remove Modal component from renderItem. Because all items modals have same visible value. So you always show last item info in modal.
You can use it;

```
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState()

const clickItem = (item)=>{
setSelectedItem(item)
setModalVisible(true)
}

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => clickItem(item)}>
        <Text style={ styles.item }>{item.task}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity> )}
```

Add modal component to below flatlist;

```
<Modal animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalVisible}
            >
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
                <Text style={styles.item}>{selectedItem.id}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks! All i had to change to your code was add in an initial useState for selectedItem!